# Google Maps for ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

Is there a google maps API for C# to use in an ASP.NET application? I've only seen posts and resources for the javascript api and was wondering if there was a c# version....

Thanks

Comment: What would it do? The Javascript API is all you need.

Comment: You realize, it probably took you longer to write this question than to just Google it?  Your exact title of this question returned 12,200,000 results.  I'm sure you'll find your answer in one of those.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers

Comment: @George That something can be located by google is no reason for not posting the question here. SO aims to be *the* source for knowledge about programming questions, and since *everything* can be found through google and a bit of work, then in that respect there would be no need for SO at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61531795

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this one with my ASP.NET site:

[GoogleMap](http://googlemap.codeplex.com/)

it seems to work pretty well

EDIT:

here are a couple more that i have not used

[Subgurim googlemaps](http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/descargar.aspx)

[Shabdar](http://www.shabdar.org/asp-net/70-google-maps-control-for-aspnet-part-1.html) - has a tutorial with it

Comment: The Artem Googlemaps control is excellent. It also has an extensions library for geocoding.