# How to call a function in google map geometry using url from .Net Core on server side?

Tags: c#, google-maps, .net-core, geometry, server-side

How to call the `isLocationOnEdge` function from .Net Core on server side?

Something like this,

```
var api= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + originLat + ',' + originLng + "&destination=" + destinationLat + ',' + destinationLng + "&key=" + apiKey;
```

Whether the `isLocationOnEdge` function could also be called like calling the direction API, is there any way to do that?

Comment: The geometry library is part of the Maps Javascript API.

Comment: I need to call it in c# code without using Javascript. And the geometry library is not supported in .Net Core

Comment: Well that's what I said. It **is** part of the Javascript API. There is no web service.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is any way to call the function as mentioned in the question? If not, if there is any alternative to do that?

Comment: I don't know how else I should say the exact same thing again. The **geometry library** is part of the **Javascript API** and there is **no web service** to access it so if you need to use these methods, you need to do it through the **Javascript API**. That was my last comment here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an alternative method to get it work from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51081327/13013258)

```
public bool isLocationOnEdge(List<Location> path, Location point, int tolerance = 2)
    {
        var C = new GeoCoordinate(point.Lat, point.Lng);
        for (int i = 0; i < path.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            var A = new GeoCoordinate(path[i].Lat, path[i].Lng);
            var B = new GeoCoordinate(path[i + 1].Lat, path[i + 1].Lng);
            if (Math.Round(A.GetDistanceTo(C) + B.GetDistanceTo(C), tolerance) == Math.Round(A.GetDistanceTo(B), tolerance))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```