# How to add places to google map using google API in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have multiple places store in my db .
places contain (Longitude,latitude,Name,Website,phone,...) .
I want to add these place to google maps using c# method.
How can I Send place to google maps ?

Comment: Google maps is a JavaScript library.

Comment: can i return list of data from database and send it to JavaScript method which send these data to google maps ?

Comment: This question isn't worded as clearly as it could be ... even though it's an interesting topic. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at this one:

[Calling JavaScript Function From CodeBehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731224/calling-javascript-function-from-codebehind)

There are two solutions:

### Use the JS

In short terms:

1. You do the Google API requests still via JS
2. Your C# Backend is doing the Database calls and
3. Routes the parameters to the JS via the above

I think that should work without a problem.

### Send API Requests purely by C#

The Google Maps API can, of course be requested by you by sending out the JSON calls.

This post gives guidance in that: [google maps API for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597229/google-maps-api-for-c-sharp)

Comment: How can I add missing place on google map using Javascript ?

Comment: @OmarSeleim What do you mean by "missing place"? In generally, google maps' API wants you to set the longitude and latitude as parameters in the calls. That's described here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=de

Comment: I want to add places with my information (name of place XX , website XX.com,Phone Number : 015647) to google map so when someone search on google map about XX my place show with description website and phone

Comment: @OmarSeleim you mean searches via google itself? Not via any of your software?
That's nothing development related. 

Please follow this guidance from google: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6320846?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Just login, and fill out the form for the respective address.

Comment: is there is not any way to send list of data to api to add them in one time?

Comment: I do not think so. Google's Maps API does only list Get-Requests from Google's database of places. Creating places does not seem to be included, which is okay, as there is an auditing behind that, I think.